# Jenkins use expression/parenthesis in shell command

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

How to make file expressions work with Jenkinsfile?
I want to run simple command `rm -rv !(_deps)` to remove all populated files except `_deps` directory. What I've tried so far:

- `sh '''rm -rv !(_deps)'''` which caused `` script.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `(' ``
- `sh 'rm -rv !\\(_deps\\)'` which caused `rm: cannot remove '!(_deps)': No such file or directory` (but it DOES exist)
- `sh 'rm -rv !\(_deps\)'` which caused `unexpected char: '\'`
- `sh 'rm -rv !(_deps)'` which caused `` syntax error near unexpected token `(' ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash to use pattern matching you have to enable [extglob](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching):

So the following will work. Make sure your shell executor is set to bash.

```
sh """
   shopt -s extglob
   rm -rv !(_deps)
  """
```

If you don't want to enable extglob you can use a different command to get the directories deleted. Following is one option.

```bash
ls | grep -v _deps | xargs rm -rv
```

In Jenkins

```
 sh """
    ls | grep -v _deps | xargs rm -rv
    """
```